# How can I call "delete" on the elements of a "vector<string>" when each string is created by a "new char[]"?

Tags: c++, memory-management, vector

I have a `vector` of strings, however these strings are created by assigning to them an array of characters. This array is created dynamically in the heap with `new`. I know that it's a good practice to free the memory that you allocate in the heap, however I'm not sure how I should free the memory of this `vector`.

When I try to do something like this:

```
for(i = 0; i < myVector.size(); i++)
     delete myVector[i];
```

It gives me this error:

> Expression must have pointer type

Here is how I declare the vector

```
vector<string> myVector;
char* s1 = new char[2];
s1[0] = 'a';
s1[1] = '\0';
myVector.push_back(s1);
char* s2 = new char[2];
s2[0] = 'b';
s2[1] = '\0';
myVector.push_back(s2);
//etc..
```

What should I do in this case?

Comment: 1. You cannot do `delete` on `string` because it deletes itself.
2. Because you mentioned `new char[]` and `string`, you've probably messed up things in initialization/assignment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you use a `vector<string>` and because `std::string` objects manage their own memory, you do not need to `delete` the elements of the vector: the strings have *copied* the content that you passed to them on creation.

However, you need to delete the C strings that you allocated with `new[]`. You should do it right after you created your `string` object: once the string is created, the character data can be safely deleted:

```
char s1 = new char[2];
s1[0] = 'a';
s1[1] = '\0';
myVector.push_back(s1);
delete[] s1;  // Here
```

Note that you picked a rather roundabout way of creating strings: you can accomplish the same exact thing by calling

```
myVector.push_back("a");
```

Answer (score 1):

Another possibility would be the use of `std::string`, i.e. `std::vector<std::string>`.

In that case you can't delete the initial memory anymore, unless you kept the pointers (which is pointless, because the `std::string` will keep ist own string copy anyway).

---

Considering your posted code, you should keep in mind that `std::string` will create ist own copy of the string you passed in the constructor, even though the constructor isn't visible due to using implicit type conversion.

Just free (`delete`) the memory right after you've put the string inside the vector. The string won't be affected by this.